# JS код обработанный с помощью browserify не доступен не из самого кода

Tags: javascript, область-видимости

Browserify прячет функции которые мне нужны для вызова через inline script в другую область видимости откуда я уже не могу их выцепить. Как избежать этой проблемы?

```
(function() {
    function r(e, n, t) {
        function o(i, f) {
            if (!n[i]) {
                if (!e[i]) {
                    var c = 'function' == typeof require && require;
                    if (!f && c) return c(i, !0);
                    if (u) return u(i, !0);
                    var a = new Error("Cannot find module '" + i + "'");
                    throw ((a.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'), a);
                }
                var p = (n[i] = { exports: {} });
                e[i][0].call(
                    p.exports,
                    function(r) {
                        var n = e[i][1][r];
                        return o(n || r);
                    },
                    p,
                    p.exports,
                    r,
                    e,
                    n,
                    t
                );
            }
            return n[i].exports;
        }
        for (
            var u = 'function' == typeof require && require, i = 0;
            i < t.length;
            i++
        )
            o(t[i]);
        return o;
    }
    return r;
})()(
    {
        1: [
               //Очень много кода содержащего все нижеизложенные функции.

                function common() {
                    initDropdowns();
                    initMobileMenu();
                }

                function frontpage() {
                    initFrontpageBanner();
                    initFrontpageSpecialists();
                    initFrontpageWorkexampleSlider();
                    initFrontpageHappyReviews();
                    initFrontpageMapDropdowns();
                    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
                        initFrontpageMapDropdowns();
                    });
                }

            },
            {}
        ]
    },
    {},
    [1]
);
```

(Функции common и frontpage должны быть доступны из inline script кода)

Comment: повесьте их на window (window.frontpage=frontpage;)

Comment: бейте все на модули и через import / export  все работает.